# Spacing around and in between the elements in a table

Tags: tables, spacing

I wanted to produce a box with numbers in it so I thought the best way would be to produce a table. However there is not enough spacing between the outside top line and the numbers, they look a bit tight. Also the numbers seem a bit far apart too, is there a better way of presenting it? Or is there a better way of doing it all together?

```
\begin{center}
                            \begin{table}
                    \begin{tabular}{|llll|}
                    \hline $4$, & $13$, & $24$, & $25$\\
                    $36$, & $43$, & $49$ & $58$\\
                    $77$, & $86$ & & \\
                    \hline
                    \end{tabular}
                \end{table}
                    \end{center}
```

Comment: Does `|*{4}{p{1cm}}|` instead of `|llll|` help? Or use a math mode column type

Comment: That helps with the columns but not the spacing between the border and the numbers. The first \hline used to produce the top of the box is too close to the 4,13,24,25 row and it would be good to have it look a bit more roomy.

Comment: You asked about better ways of presenting, I offered you a way with  `booktabs` which is a widely well-received package, but alas, you stick to the vertical lines, so I've deleted my answer, since it was no of use to you, apparently

Comment: Expressions such as "not enough spacing", "look a bit tight", and "seem a bit far apart" are a bit vague and imprecise. Please take the time to clarify what the values of the layout parameters should be.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different solutions, if you don't need a `table` environment: one with the `matrix` environment and the `\boxed` command, the other with the `empheq` environment, which adds optional arguments to the `ams` environments:

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, empheq}
\newcommand\widefbox[1]{\setlength\fboxsep{2ex}\fbox{\quad\;#1\enspace}}

\begin{document}

 \[ \setlength\fboxsep{0.4em}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}\boxed{\quad\;\begin{matrix*}
       4 & 13 & 24 & 25\\
       \mathclap{E=mc^2} & & & \\
      36 & 43 & 49 & 58 \\
      77 & 86 & & \end{matrix*}} \]
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{alignat* = 4}
       & 4 & \quad & 13 & \quad & 24 & \quad & 25\\
        & \mathclap{E=mc^2} \\
       & 36 & & 43 & & 49 & & 58 \\
       & 77 & & 86
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: In both solutions? I might change the value of `\arraycolsep`, but the O.P. complained the columns were too far apart. Of course, I might ask that columns  be right or left aligned.

Comment: @Mico: Oh! I see. It was not in th e O.P.'s question.  Well, that will simplify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Does the following look satisfy your objectives? The solution uses a centered `array` environment; using an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment is convenient for the table at hand since it saves you 18 `$` keystrokes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}  % for "\extrarowheight" macro
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % default: 0pt
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}    % default: 5pt
   $\begin{array}{|rrrr|}
   \hline 
    4 & 13 & 24 & 25\\
   36 & 43 & 49 & 58\\
   77 & 86 &    &   \\
   \hline
   \end{array}$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```